# dragging cannot get to the beginning of chart highcharts

Tags: highcharts

when I drag highchart and pull the chart to right ,I can not reach to left corner of chart 
like this image below

always remain space between `navigator` and the left arrow
[image: space between end of the chart and navigator]

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ne1xwc2n/

Comment: This is known issue, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4076). I added comment with your demo, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set ordinal:false in xAsix and the problem was resolve